# Show G=g with constraints

Tags: calculus

Show that $G(x,y,z)=g(u,v)$ with $\left\{\begin{matrix}
u=x^2+yz\\ 
v=y^2+xz
\end{matrix}\right.$ satisfy $$(2y^2-xz)\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}+(2x^2-yz)\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}+(2z^2-4xy)\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}=0$$

Where do i start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that

$\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$

$\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$

$\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}$

which means

$\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}2x+\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}z$

$\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}z+\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}2y$

$\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}y+\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}x$

$(2y^2-xz)\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}+(2x^2-yz)\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}+(2z^2-4xy)\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}=0$

Comment: The chain rule, that makes sense. Thanks!